# Autodesk Forge java tutorial new bucket creation failure

Tags: java, autodesk-forge

I was following autodesk forge tutorial for java, but using their code examples, new bucket creation fails for me with almost no error information except " com.autodesk.client.ApiException: error". So I was wondering if anyone else already tried to create simple viewer using their tutorial and managed to solve this problem or at least encountered it.
Their sample program in GitHub is sadly incomplete, so I can't exactly check if there are any mistakes regarding servlet mappings.

```
    com.autodesk.client.ApiClient.invokeAPI(ApiClient.java:581),
    com.autodesk.client.api.BucketsApi.createBucket(BucketsApi.java:113),
    forgesample.oss.doPost(oss.java:141),
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661),
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742),
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231),
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166),
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52),
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193),
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166),
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198),
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96),
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496),
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140),
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81),
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650),
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87),
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342),
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803),
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66),
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790),
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468),
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49),
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142),
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617),
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61),
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**EDIT**
Apparently using a more unique bucket name I managed to create one, but the given error was plain 400 and stack trace does not give exactly much help.

Comment: I'm sorry about thus problem, can you please add the full call stack when the error happens? Thanks!

Comment: @AugustoGoncalves I updated the question, but also managed to solve it. Still it's not exactly informative when the reason is http 400 and no extra information.

Comment: @WidnmaxJ,The Java code of this tutorial 
 does not throw out raw error because the JAVA SDK has taken care of. To make the error simpler, the tutorial only prints the generic error.  sorry about this problem. We can enhance the workflow. As to the error 400, may I know if your bucket name has followed the rule: -_.a-z0-9 (between 3-128 characters in length)? With my experience, normally 400 means the bucket name is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, here are the requirements for [bucket names](http://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-POST/):

> A unique name you assign to a bucket. It must be globally unique
>   across all applications and regions, otherwise the call will fail.
>   Possible values: -_.a-z0-9 (between 3-128 characters in length). Note
>   that you cannot change a bucket key.

And thanks @WidnmaxJ for the feedback, [logged](https://github.com/Developer-Autodesk/forge.learning/issues/11) for improvements on the tutorial.